# What is the X axis of a binary text classification and why does my graph look so messed up?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp

I'm trying to input a sentence and classify it as a 1 or 0. I have data with two columns, the first is the sentence text (e.g. "This is a sentence") and the second column is a classification (e.g. 0 or 1).

I have predicted values that I'm trying to interpret, only I can't seem to understand the X axis of my graph and why my Regression line looks like the way it does.

```py
import nltk
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score, mean_squared_error, r2_score
from sklearn import linear_model

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(labor_data['text'],labor_data['label_one'],random_state=0)
vect = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,1),min_df=0,max_df=.25).fit(X_train)
X_train_vectorized = vect.transform(X_train)
lr_model = linear_model.LinearRegression()

lr_model.fit(X_train_vectorized,Y_train)
lr_predictions = lr_model.predict(vect.transform(X_test))

plt.scatter(X_test, Y_test,  color='black')
plt.plot(X_test, lr_predictions, color='blue', linewidth=3)

plt.xticks(())
plt.yticks(())

plt.show()
```

I understand the Y Axis is values, but don't understand the X axis or my regression line. I know my lr_predictions are values between 0 and 1, as are all the values on the plot. But shouldn't the line be a downward sloped straight line?

Graph
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5esYE.jpg

Comment: Could you give a glimpse over what's on your "vect" variable?

Comment: It's just a CountVectorizer
```CountVectorizer(analyzer='word', binary=False, decode_error='strict',
                dtype=<class 'numpy.int64'>, encoding='utf-8', input='content',
                lowercase=True, max_df=0.25, max_features=None, min_df=0,
                ngram_range=(1, 1), preprocessor=None, stop_words=None,
                strip_accents=None, token_pattern='(?u)\\b\\w\\w+\\b',
                tokenizer=None, vocabulary=None)
```

Comment: What's the output like? Print X_train_vectorized.

Answer (score 0):

The blue line in your example is not a regression line, it is a line connecting all the predicted values

```
import nltk
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score, mean_squared_error, r2_score
from sklearn import linear_model
%matplotlib inline


df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['text','label_one'])
df = df.append({'text': 'The American Cocker Spaniel is a breed of sporting dog.', 'label_one':0}, ignore_index=True)
df = df.append({'text': 'The Kooikerhondje is a small spaniel-type breed of dog of Dutch ancestry that was originally used as a working dog', 'label_one':0}, ignore_index=True)
df = df.append({'text': 'the dog is running outside.', 'label_one':0}, ignore_index=True)
df = df.append({'text': 'Poodles are a group of formal dog breeds, the Standard Poodle, Miniature Poodle and Toy Poodle.', 'label_one':0}, ignore_index=True)
df = df.append({'text': 'The Chihuahua is the smallest breed of dog, and is named after the Mexican state of Chihuahua. ', 'label_one':0}, ignore_index=True)
df = df.append({'text': 'The Maine Coon is the largest domesticated cat breed.', 'label_one':1}, ignore_index=True)
df = df.append({'text': 'The Persian cat is a long-haired breed of cat characterized by its round face and short muzzle. ', 'label_one':1}, ignore_index=True)
df = df.append({'text': 'The cat (Felis catus) is a small carnivorous mammal', 'label_one':1}, ignore_index=True)
df = df.append({'text': 'The cat is sleeping on the rug', 'label_one':1}, ignore_index=True)



X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(list(df['text']),list(df['label_one']))
vect = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,1),min_df=1,max_df=1.0).fit(X_train)
X_train_vectorized = vect.transform(X_train)
lr_model = linear_model.LinearRegression()

lr_model.fit(X_train_vectorized,Y_train)
lr_predictions = lr_model.predict(vect.transform(X_test))

plt.scatter(range(len(X_test)), Y_test,  color='black')
plt.plot(range(len(X_test)), lr_predictions, color='blue', linewidth=3)

plt.xticks(())
plt.yticks(())

plt.show()
for s in X_test:
    print(s)
```

output:
[image]

Some remarks:

1) In your example, you are using linear regression (not logistic regression) so your predicted values are not necessarily between 0 and 1. For example the second sentence in the plot above has a negative predicted value.

2) This is multiple linear regression because there are more than one explanatory variables.

looking at X_train_vectorized 
tells us that it is a:

> <6x36 sparse matrix of type ''
>       with 53 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

So in the example data above there are 36 explanatory variables (or "input variables").

We can also look at the model coefficients:

```
print(len(lr_model.coef_))
```

> 36

The linear model created indeed has 36 coefficients (in addition to the model intercept)

```
print(lr_model.intercept_)
```

> 0.3333333333333333